# Within Azure, how can you make two active directories share the same application?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am currently use a multi-tenanted application, and have authentication working for a single azure AD. I would like to have multiple ADs connected to the authentication of the authentication page. How can I do so from within the Azure administrator console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question: you setup a multi-tenant app in the properties of the application in Azure, but currently your application only accepts user of one tenant to sign-in.

If this is the case, then what you have to do is to also adjust your application's code to be multi-tenant. In order to enable multi-tenancy on your application:

1. Double check you have set `Multi-Tenanted` property to `Yes` on your application registration's information in the Azure Portal (by default, applications created in the Azure Portal are configured as single-tenant)
2. Update your code to send requests to the `'common'` endpoint (update the endpoint from `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{yourtenant}` to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common`)
3. For some platforms, like ASP.NET, you need also to update your code to accept multiple issuers

For more information about multi-tenancy, see: [How to sign in any Azure Active Directory (AD) user using the multi-tenant application pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-devhowto-multi-tenant-overview).

Comment: Just to clarify #3, if you want to limit the access to your app for specific ADs, you'll need to validate the issuer claim in the token (on a web service) to verify it's from one of the tokens that's allowed to access your app. If you're happy to allow any tenant to sign in (full multi-tenancy), then you do not need to worry about this step.

Comment: The current issue I am having is using the Id:Client and Id:Password of two ADs within the web.config file. I can't seem to use that for two different ADs simultaneously.

Comment: Sorry thats the ida:ClientId and ida:Password

Comment: The fact that you mentioned that you are using the client/password from two different ADs tells me that your application may be a *single-tenant app*. Multi-tenant apps only need one clientId / key from the application object created in any your *home* tenant: for example, if you registered an application in the tenant *contoso.com*, you should use the clientId/key from this application only in your code/Web.Config file. When a user signs-in from *fabrikam.com*, a *service principal* is created in the *fabrikam.com* tenant with reference to your app. There is no need for you to control this.

Comment: For more information please see [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-application-objects)

Comment: @JamesEdwards It seems that you post several similar issue in the forum.  Do you have any update about this issue?

Comment: I made the multi-tenant application, but am failing to get the other AD's users to log in.

Comment: @JamesEdwards - can you provide additional details? What failing means? Do they receive error messages? Can you post screen shots including the URLs?